# Return ' ' from int in Case statement in SQL Server XML result

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I'm trying to render a person table into XML. My NAME field is a varchar while my AGE field is an int. Every time it is NULL the XML conversion is turning it into 0. I'd like it to be ' ' (if it was NULL then the XML skips the field).

```
SELECT (SELECT CASE WHEN NAME IS NULL THEN ' ' ELSE NAME END,
               CASE WHEN AGE IS NULL THEN ' ' ELSE AGE END
               FROM TABLE.PERSONS FOR XML PATH('PERSON'), TYPE)
FOR XML PATH('PERSONS'), TYPE
```

The Result is when age is NULL is:

```
<PERSONS>
    <PERSON>
        <NAME>JIM</NAME>
        <AGE>0</AGE>
    </PERSON>
</PERSONS>
```

What I'd like it to be is:

```
<PERSONS>
    <PERSON>
        <NAME>JIM</NAME>
        <AGE> </AGE>
    </PERSON>
</PERSONS>
```

Comment: What is the datatype of `Age` column? `INT`?

Comment: Yes it is. It's in the second sentence of my description.

Comment: This is because a single space string when implicitly converted to an int is 0. You would have to convert Age to varchar in your query.

Comment: This may well cause issues with the consuming application if it expects `age` to be numeric. You could also consider `,TYPE, ELEMENTS XSINIL`

Comment: All 3 answers work so I've upvoted them all. Larnu's was the shortest path so I chose it as the correct answer.

Comment: Martin - I'm rendering the results to a static web page so an Int datatype is more of a hindrance in this scenario.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`' '` is a `varchar`, not an `int`. In your `CASE` expression your value `' '` is therefore implicitly cast to an `int` (as `int` has a higher [data type precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) than a `varchar`). If you try `SELECT CONVERT(int, ' ');` you'll notice the return value is `0`.

You'll need to convert your age to a `varchar`:

```
SELECT (SELECT CASE WHEN NAME IS NULL THEN ' ' ELSE NAME END AS NAME,
               CASE WHEN AGE IS NULL THEN ' ' ELSE CONVERT(varchar(3),AGE) END AS AGE --I assume you no will have the age 1000 (or more)
               FROM TABLE.PERSONS FOR XML PATH('PERSON'), TYPE)
FOR XML PATH('PERSONS'), TYPE;
```

I also noted, your `CASE` expressions were missing their `END`s.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the END missing. Your solution fixed the problem.

Comment: You was quicker than me, while I was waiting the OP to answer my question in the comment, well done ;)

Answer (score 4):

If 2012+, another option is to use NULLIF() and Concat()

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable table (Name varchar(50),Age int)
Insert Into @YourTable values
 ('Jim',0)
,('Jane',null)
,('John',25)

Select Name = IsNull(Name,'')
      ,Age  = concat('',NullIf(Age,0))
 From  @YourTable 
 For XML Path('PERSON'),Root('PERSONS')
```

**Returns**

```
<PERSONS>
  <PERSON>
    <Name>Jim</Name>
    <Age></Age>
  </PERSON>
  <PERSON>
    <Name>Jane</Name>
    <Age></Age>
  </PERSON>
  <PERSON>
    <Name>John</Name>
    <Age>25</Age>
  </PERSON>
</PERSONS>
```

Answer (score 1):

Case statement looks at the source column data type(int) and converts an empty string to `0` int being a data type of higher precedence, simple solution would be to use a sub-query to convert the int data type to a string and then use the case statement. Something like...

```
SELECT (SELECT CASE WHEN NAME IS NULL THEN ' ' ELSE NAME END Name,
               CASE WHEN AGE IS NULL THEN  ' ' ELSE AGE END  Age
        FROM
        (SELECT NAME , CAST(AGE AS VARCHAR(10)) AS AGE FROM Table.Persons) x
        FOR XML PATH('PERSON'), TYPE)
FOR XML PATH('PERSONS'), TYPE
```